# Modification of chapter headings

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I'm using document class `report` and I have decided for chapter headings to use one of the predefined style of Vincent Zoonekynd's like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\LigneVerticale{\vrule height 1.5cm depth 0.9cm\hspace{0.1cm}\relax}
\def\LignesVerticales{%
  \let\LV\LigneVerticale\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV}
\def\GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre#1{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\color{white}%
  \rlap{\vrule height 0.8cm width 1cm depth 0.2cm}%
  \rlap{\hbox to 1cm{\hss\mbox{\color{black}#1}\hss}}%
  \vrule height 0pt width 1cm depth 0pt}}}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
    \vspace*{-20pt}
    \hbox{%
    \huge\bfseries
    \LignesVerticales
    \hspace{-0.5cm}%
    \GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre{\thechapter}
    \hspace{0.2cm}\hbox{#1}%
}\par\vskip 0.5cm}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1
    \vspace*{-20pt}
   {\hbox{%
    \huge\bfseries
    \LignesVerticales
    %\hspace{0.5cm}%
    \hbox{#1}%
}\par\vskip 0.3cm}
\makeatother

    \begin{document}
    \chapter{Here we go}
    \end{document}
```

However, I would like to make some changes.

1. I would need to move all construction up to the page, in other words to get smaller space between the top of any page and the construction.
2. I would like to change the small box. I would prefer white square with black number (not like this one-black square with white number).

Comment: I've taken the liberty of expanding your code into a compilable MWE (minimum working example), incorporating your note that you use the `report` document class. The main change is that I had to change the instruction `\white #1` to `\textcolor{white}{#1}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Since you've redefined `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead` (responsible for creating the entire chapter header when using `\chapter` and `\chapter*`, respectively), the chapter heading starts at the top of the text block. You may be referring to moving the entire text block up (or reduce the top margin). For this I would suggest using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry).
2. Here's a MWE that provides what you're after. However, inserting a white block with a black number doesn't show up as needed:

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{report}
   \usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
   \usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

   \makeatletter
   \def\LigneVerticale{\vrule height 2cm depth 1.4cm\hspace{0.1cm}\relax}
   \def\LignesVerticales{%
     \let\LV\LigneVerticale\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV}
   \def\GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre#1{{%
     \color{white}%
     \rlap{\vrule height 0.8cm width 1cm depth 0.2cm}%
     \rlap{\hbox to 1cm{\hss\mbox{\color{black}#1}\hss}}%
     \vrule height 0pt width 1cm depth 0pt}}

   \def\@makechapterhead#1{\hbox{%
       \huge\bfseries
       \LignesVerticales
       \hspace{-0.5cm}%
       \GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre{\thechapter}
       \hspace{0.2cm}\hbox{#1}%
   }\par\vskip 0.3cm}

   \def\@makeschapterhead#1{\hbox{%
       \huge\bfseries
       \LignesVerticales
       %\hspace{0.5cm}%
       \hbox{#1}%
   }\par\vskip 0.3cm}
   \makeatother

   \begin{document}

   \chapter{A chapter}

   \end{document}
   ```

   The following definition of `\GrosCarreAveUnChiffre`

   ```
   \def\GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre#1{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
     \fbox{\color{white}%
     \rlap{\vrule height 0.8cm width 1cm depth 0.2cm}%
     \rlap{\hbox to 1cm{\hss\mbox{\color{black}#1}\hss}}%
     \vrule height 0pt width 1cm depth 0pt}}}
   ```

   yields a boxes chapter number:

   [image]

   Another alternative - moving the header construction vertically is obtained using

   ```
   \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
     \vspace*{\dimexpr-\headsep-\headheight-\baselineskip}%
     \hbox{%
       \huge\bfseries
       \LignesVerticales
       \hspace{-0.5cm}%
       \GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre{\thechapter}
       \hspace{0.2cm}\hbox{#1}%
   }\par\vskip 0.3cm}

   \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
     \vspace*{\dimexpr-\headsep-\headheight-\baselineskip}%
     \hbox{%
       \huge\bfseries
       \LignesVerticales
       %\hspace{0.5cm}%
       \hbox{#1}%
   }\par\vskip 0.3cm}
   ```

   which moves the vertical lines to the top of the page header. Of course, replacing the expression within `\vspace*` with a fixed dimension (say, `-30pt`) will displace it vertically with that amount.

   [image]

   [`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) was added to highlight the text block boundary (in response to (1) above).

Comment: &Werner: Thank you. That's almost what I wanted. I just wanted to ask if you know how to put around the white square black borders.

Comment: Don't use showframe package in the above. The rest of it is defined as above. Now I want to move all together (lines and chapter number and chapter name) up closer to the top of the page. I don't like too much empty space above the construction.

Comment: @Jane: As mentioned in my answer, you don't need to [`showframe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe). I just added it to provide a frame of reference. So, by all means, remove it. It should solve your problem of moving the header upward by inserting `\vspace*{<len>}` (where you specify `<len>`, a *negative* length) as I've indicated.